# Java - Highest number in a column multi-array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

It seems that I go out of bounds in the following code (see the line with the comment) and I can't seem to fix the problem. Am I overlooking or forgetting something here?

```
int[][] num = {   {10,2,5},
                  {5,1,0},
                  {25,35,16,20,19},
                  {26,27,100} };

for (int col = 0; col < num.length; col++) {
    int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int row = 0; row < num[col].length + 1; row++)
        if (num[row][col] > highest) //this is where I get the error.
            highest = num[row][col];
    System.out.println( "Highest number in column " + col + " = " + highest);
}
```

Comment: Your inner for loop cannot go to length +1. length is enough.

Comment: You inverted row and col in your for loops. The outer loop actually iterates through rows. The inner loop actually iterates through columns of this row.

Comment: @JBNizet That's because the OP wanted to find the max number in each column, so it makes sense. The ranges of the loops are wrong though.

Comment: @Terje - It prints 25 if I don't include +1 to the .length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the maximum number of each column, first you have to find the longest row, in order to know what the range of your outer loop should be :

```
int longestRow = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < num.length; row++)
    if (num[row].length > longestRow)
        longestRow = num[row].length;
```

Then you can iterate over each column, but you have to check for each row you reach that the current column exists in that row :

```
for ( int col = 0; col < longestRow; col++)
{
   int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   for ( int row = 0; row < num.length; row++)
        if ( col < num[row].length && num[row][col] > highest) 
            highest = num[row][col];
    System.out.println( "Highest number in column " + col + " = " + highest);
}
```

Output :

```
Highest number in column 0 = 26
Highest number in column 1 = 35
Highest number in column 2 = 100
Highest number in column 3 = 20
Highest number in column 4 = 19
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Ok, first find the longest row:
int longest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int[] row : num) {
    longest = Math.max(longest, row.length);
}

// then, create an array to store max column values:
int[] rowHigh = new int[longest];
for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
    rowHigh[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}

// then iterate over initial array to find max values of each column
for (int[] row : num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        rowHigh[i] = Math.max(rowHigh[i], row[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the highest number of each column, not the maximum of each row.

Answer (score 0):

in 2D array, like yours num[a][b], array.length gives number of rows. 
to get the number of columns in row[i] use this : array[i].length. i.e. get the number of columns in i'th row

Use following code: 
        int[][] num = {   {10,2,5},
                {5,1,0},
                {25,35,16,20,19},
                {26,27,100} };

```
    int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int row = 0 ,col = 0;
     for ( row = 0; row < num.length; row++ )
     {
         for ( col = 0; col < num[row].length; col++ )
             if (num[row][col] > highest )
                 highest = num[row][col];
     }
     System.out.println( "Highest number in row:"+row+" column:" + col + ". Highest value is: " + highest );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8

```
int[][] num = {{10, 2, 5},
        {5, 1, 0},
        {25, 35, 16, 20, 19},
        {26, 27, 100}};


int max = Stream.of(num) // give me a stream of int[]
                // unpack those int[] into an IntStream
                .flatMapToInt(arr -> IntStream.of(arr))
                // find the maximum.
                .max()
                // as a plain int value.
                .getAsInt();
System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: As an addendum for your solution, in the flatMapToInt, you can use `IntStream::of` instead, which prevents explicit mapping. The resulting code is `Stream.of(num).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).max().getAsInt()`